# how to create IMobileServiceTableQuery<T>.Select Method visual source

Tags: c#, android, sql, visual-studio, azure-mobile-services

how can I create a query to get the email and the password returns the ID with xamarin.android platform using azure mobile services

Example:

```
MobileServiceTableQuery<TodoItem> query = todoTable
    .Select(todoItem => todoItem.Text);
List<string> items = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a query to get the email and the password returns the ID with xamarin.android platform using azure mobile services

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to filter the item under your remote table with the specific email and password, then return the ID.

For the online client, you could use the following code:

```
IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> onlineTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
var items = await onlineTable
    .Where(t => t.Email == "xxx" && t.Password == "xxx")
    .Select(t => t.Id).ToListAsync();
```

Moreover, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Query Support in Online Clients](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#query-support-in-online-clients).